# How to define a templated variable which is inside a class

Tags: c++, templates

I have two files `quantity.h` and `main.cpp` whose contents are below

file `quantity.h`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
template <typename T = unsigned int>
class quantity
{
    enum volume {ltr,gallon,oz};

    public:
    using ret = std::pair<volume,T>;
    ret get_volume()
    {
        return std::make_pair(ltr,5);
    }
    
};
```

Then I have `main.cpp`

```
#include<quantity.h>
int main() {
    quantity <unsigned int> q1;
    ret t = q1.get_volume();

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles if I only call `q1.get_volume();` but I want to store the result in a `std::pair ret` which is declared/defined in `quantity.h` file .
I get compilation error for the code as

```
error: 'ret' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: `quantity<T>::ret` is not a variable; it's a type alias.

Comment: In the `main` function there's no type or symbol such as `ret` in scope. Only `quantity<unsigned int>::ret`. A better solution would be to use auto type deduction like `auto t = q1.get_volume();`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I also have to declare functions in other .h file with ret as return type;

Answer (score -1):

Use auto, and let the compiler do the deduction work for you :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T = unsigned int>
class quantity
{
    enum volume { ltr, gallon, oz };

public:

    auto get_volume()
    {
        return std::make_pair(ltr, 5);
    }

};

int main() 
{
    quantity <unsigned int> q1;
    auto t = q1.get_volume();
    return 0;
}
```